# Pysical Server 2 NICS LAN and DMZ

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, local-area-network, nic, dmz

I'm after some advice. I have a Physical server with 2 on-board NICs. Currently only one is used for LAN.

If I wanted to setup Hyper-V and use the second NIC for DMZ stuff, is that possible?

I worry that the server will use the try to use the DMZ NIC instead of the LAN nic for network and external access.

Thanks,
Lee.

EDIT: 
Complete picture:
1x Physical Server 2 NICs one setup as LAN, one setup as DMZ.
I can pass through the required NIC to the VM fine, but when trying to browse the internet on the physical server, I get sever time out as I think it's trying to use the DMZ NIC, not the LAN NIC.

Comment: When you say a DMZ, is that a virtual switch configured as an Internal network for the VM?  Is the LAN NIC on a vSwitch at all - if so as an external?  Assuming those are both correct, I'd imagine you've got your DNS setting incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V will only use the NIC that you "bind" the DMZ virtual switch to if you allow the management operating system to share that virtual switch. For the DMZ virtual switch you would not enable that option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir, i just re-read and that's correct and has worked THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to help...